# Quest flaw of "I refuse to hide from my foes"

Tags: curse-of-strahd

I was playing The Artifact as a rogue, and in game I was given the Gift of Prophecy which comes with an ability you can use twice before it vanishes, but has the caveat of *altering appearance* and adding the flaw of *I refuse to hide from my foes*, both of which say nothing about going away. So does that mean I can never hide when I perceive hostility? What about cover? Seems like an absolutely ridiculous quest flaw if not even a *Remove curse* spell can get rid of it.

Comment: What RPG system and edition are you playing. For example are you playing D&D 5e?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @Rubiksmoose This is tagged dnd-adventurers-league, so it has to be DnD 5e since that's the only system they support.

Comment: @nick012000 you're probably right but that tag was added by another user, not the OP. And since this question was asked April 10 and the OP was last online Oct 18, I'm half tempted to remove it since it is kinda, almost a guess at the system (though I suppose it does no harm at the moment, even with the CoS tag as well) and obviously the OP hasn't bothered to come back to clarify the question. Also, as stated by answers on [this meta post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8045/14878) non-system tags don't indicate that the question *is* about the system the tag excerpts may describe.